# Is this a lie group?

Tags: general-topology, geometry, lie-groups

Assume $G$ is a Lie group. Let $\pi\colon P\to M$ be a principal fiber bundle with structural group $G$ which acts on the right. (Fibers are all isomorphic to $G$.)

Let $C(P,G)$ be the set of all maps $\tau\colon P\to G$ such that $$\tau(pg)=g^{-1}\tau(p).$$ 
One can replace $G$ in $C(P,G)$ by a vector space $V$ such that $G\to \mathrm{GL}(V)$ is given representation.

> Is this $C(P,G)$ a Lie group?

The reason I am asking this is due to the following facts. Denote $GA(P)$ the group of gauge transformations of $P$, i.e. $f\in GA(P)$ iff all the following hold:

- $f\colon P\to P$ is an automorphism,
- $f$ descends to $M$ as $\mathrm{Id}_M$,
- $f(pg)=f(p)g$.

Then $GA(P)^{op}\cong C(P,G)$ are isomorphic as groups (where $op$ means [opposite group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opposite_group)).

Furthermore, let $\mathfrak{g}$ to be the Lie algebra of $G$. There is an "exponential map" $\overline{\exp}\colon C(P,\mathfrak g)\to C(P,G)$. 
My guess is that $C(P,\mathfrak g)$ is the tangent space of $C(P,G)$.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Sorry. It is $G$. It is corrected now.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the statement "One can replace $G$ in $C(P,G)$ by vector space $V$ s.t. $G \to GL(V)$ is given representation." How is $G$ still there after you replaced it with $V$? Are there two different $G$'s around?

Comment: @Vincent I mean consider $G\to Homeo(V)$. Then $C(P,V)$ is defined similarly. $C(P,V)$ really defines the sections of $P\times_GV$ associated bundle.

Comment: What is your definition of a Lie group? Do you assume that it is locally homeomorphic to a finite-dimensional Euclidean space or you allow groups modeled on Hilbert/Banach/topological vector spaces? Also, I think you should specify topology and group structure on $C(P,G)$ (just for the sake of completeness of the question).

Comment: @MoisheKohan This is only mentioned in Bleecker's Gauge Theory and Variational Principles book. It says there is "lie algebra" $C(P,\mathcal{G})$ inherited from $G$ and there is exponent map $exp:C(P,\mathcal{G})\to C(P,G)$. My guess this is a "lie group" which might be non-finite dimensional. There is no real good reason for me to believe this is finite dimensional lie group. Maybe you can clarify what kind of "lie group" I should be looking into.